# LinkedIn Cruise Control authenticaton in AWS Prometheus

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, prometheus

We are going to integrate LinkedIn Cruise-Control(CC) in our Kafka stack.
The flow looks:
Kafka(AWS MSK brokers) ->(sends metrics) -> AWS Prometheus ->(consume metrics) -> Cruise Control.
But when CC tries to fetch metrics from AWS Prometheus, it fails with an error:

> ERROR Error when attempting to query Prometheus metrics java.io.IOException: Received non-success response code on Prometheus API HTTP call, response code = 403, response body = {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}

Does anyone configured cruise-control to fetch metrics from AWS Prometheus? How we can specify user's credentials to let CC to authenticate itself?

Comment: Have you added any passwords or tokens anywhere? Tried contacting AWS support how to connect? Tried using just Grafana with that Prometheus? Error doesn't seem unique to Cruise Control

Comment: Yeah, we contacted AWS support. They asked us to use Gateway or add an IAM role to EC2 instance where CC is launched. But it doesn't work for us. We decided to run Prometheus without authentication in our stack:)

Comment: _We decided to run Prometheus without authentication in our stack_ Did this solve your initial issue? If so please add it as an answer.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani no, we didn't. More over, we had postpone to use this tool.